# Can't resize Component Shape in MS Visio 2007

Tags: windows, uml, microsoft-visio-2007

How can I re-size the `Component Shape` in **MS Visio 2007**? I know that I can resize it by grabbing the corners but it appears to be locked.

[image: Component Shape in UML Visio]

Comment: My first instinct is to tell you to grab a corner handle and drag... But I'm guessing there may be more to your intended question.  Can you elaborate if required?

Comment: Ohh I know that I can grab the corner and resize. But it is not happening because it is locked or somewhat!

Answer (score 4):

You have to unlock the shape's protection first. After that you will be able to resize the shape. Here is how it is done in **Visio 2013**:

First you need to enable the Developer Tab in your Visio. Check how it is done [here](http://www.visguy.com/2008/08/04/top-9-reasons-for-turning-on-developer-mode/). After that mark your shape with the mouse and go to the Developer Tab, click on protection and uncheck width and height. Now you should be able to resize the shape. It is done similar in Visio 2007, click [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/prevent-or-allow-changes-to-shapes-HP001231138.aspx).

Comment: Just tried this. After removing all the protection the shape had (like height, width, rotation, ...) I am still not able to scale it.

Comment: @fgysin sometimes you have to do it more times. Or delete and create again the component and then try again what I described.

Answer (score 1):

The grey handles (the little boxes at the corners and middles) definitely mean it's locked.  They'd probably be blue otherwise (the default is blue).

So to unlock, first be sure you're in "developer" mode because I'm pretty sure that you can only look at the page if you're not in developer mode.  Then right-click on the shape, select "format" from the pop-up, and then "protection".  Set protection to "none" (or uncheck one or more protected dimensions/qualities if you don't want to un-protect everything).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [checking shape protection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Prevent-or-allow-changes-to-shapes-e65decf4-0eed-4fd6-a7d9-b286abcbc7eb), you should check **ShapeSheet** > **Shape Transform** and look for the [`Guard()` function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/guard-function). To view the **ShapeSheet** - right-click the shape and select "Show ShapeSheet".

This was stumping me as well - I managed to remove the formula by entering values into the `Width`, `Height`, `PinX`, and `PinY` - depending on where you see the formula being used.

#### ShapeSheet > Shape Transform

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if the ShapeSheet has a "User-defined Cells" section, with, for instance, "User.SetWidth" having a value that DEPENDSON() something, you can change the value to 1 to enable changing the width.