# Can't resize Visio 2010 entities

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010, diagrams

Please don't mark as a duplicate ([this](https://superuser.com/questions/749621/cant-resize-component-shape-in-ms-visio-2007) is a similar question). I am making a Database diagram in Visio 2010, but when I add a table entity, I can't resize it. I've tried changing the protection, I've messed about with the ShapeSheet, and the best I can do is to get the points around the edge to turn blue (they still don't drag though).

The weird thing is, when I add a different entity, and set the protection to None, I can reshape it just fine! Why is this? Am I missing something or is Visio just being weird?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem in Visio Standard 2013 with the ORM Diagram "Entity" Shape.  I was able to resize the shape by doing the following:

(1) right-click on the shape and select "Show Shapesheet".

(2) In the section for "Shape Transform", Remove the "GUARD" function from the Width and Height fields (see image below).  I left the rest of the function and only deleted the word "GUARD".

(3) In the section for "Protection", set the LockWidth and LockHeight fields to 0 instead of 1.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a6ff.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Entity shape is not designed to be manually resized. The width and height are calculated from the size of the text within the various data fields within the shape. Data is entered via the Database Properties dialog.